# authorize method called twice for Facebook on Android

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

I made the mistake of calling `authorize` during a valid session.
I was very surprised to see that second call didn't show the Facebook login form, it just reused the token.

Is this behaviour normal?

Comment: Can you please specify more details? Which facebook url are you going to invoke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is normal behaviour.

If you call login and have a valid token then you will skip the login form and go straight to the onComplete callback.

Comment: Great. This make life easy :). Instead of checking token validity by request - now I'll call autorize before my requests :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the Facebook API specifically, but this behavior does not surprise me. If you're writing a mid-to-large application, you might have several parts calling the Facebook API independently. There is no reason to prompt the user for credentials twice, so your application should only prompt the first time authorization is required. It's not difficult for the library to check whether you've already authenticated, and reuse the credentials that it's stored in memory (a session cookie, in fact). This way, you don't need to do anything special if you take two independent modules that happen to make Facebook connections and put them together.